# Recording time elapsed around area(Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer

I am new to unity and wanted to create a scene that has a moveable object and a displayed grid. When the object is moved to the grid area I want it to record the time spent on the grid, and once it leaves the designated grid area I want to receive the time it spent in the grid. I have attempted with this code.

```
if (collision.gameObject.name == "GridHolder")
{
    stopwatch.Start();
    isInSection1 = true;
    isInSection2 = false;
    Debug.Log("In area");
    if (!(collision.gameObject.name == "GridHolder"))
    {
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Debug.Log("Left area");
        Debug.LogFormat("Time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);

    }
}
```

I have tried this and it will not to display the time. I tested out if it does record time with a time elapsed statement in the first if statement. It does record the time and continues to record and elapse the time when I bring the object back to the area.

Answer (score 1):

The stopwatch function does not pause your code/await, so your check if the gameobject left will never be run, as that ifstatement can only run when your first ifstatement is run(basiclly it will always be false).

```
if(collision.gameObject.name == "GridHolder"){
    if (!(collision.gameObject.name == "GridHolder")){
        //This if statement will never run, as the previous if statement contradicts this one.
}
```

You should use [OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) and [OnTriggerExit](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerExit.html) to start and stop you stopwatch.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on ChilliPenguin (14082731)'s answer, the reason your code never reaches the inside is because your conditions specify that, in order to run the outer block of code, the collider must be your grid, and then in order to run the inner block of code, the collider must also not be your grid. Specifically, you're saying to reach the inner block, the collider must

1. Be the grid
2. Not be the grid

at the same time, which I'm sure you can tell is never going to happen. Rather, what you want is some way to tell when the object *starts* touching the grid, using, say, [Collider.OnCollisionEnter(Collision)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html), and start the stopwatch when it happens. Then, you want to tell when the object *stops* touching the grid, using, say, [Collider.OnCollisionExit(Collision)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionExit.html), and stop the stopwatch when that happens. So, in some form, you'd have something like,

```
/* ... */
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "GridHolder") {
        stopwatch.Start();
        Debug.Log("In area");
    }
}

void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision) {
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "GridHolder") {
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Debug.Log("Left area");
        Debug.LogFormat("Time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
    }
}
/* ... */
```

If you'd like to know when it enters/exits a region rather than starts/stops touching a grid, you can use [triggers](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) [instead](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerExit.html) of colliders, but the premise is the same.